# save Silverlight 5 web application screen shot to disk

Tags: silverlight, screenshot

I want to take a screen shot from my web-based Silverlight 5 application and save it on disk, what are my options? I've searched a lot but found nothing useful.

Comment: I assume that you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I have some controls in my XAMl, then I want to take a capture when user clicks on a button, then user should be able to download captured image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-a-Silverlight-Screen.aspx) appears to capture and save it to disk

**Capture**

```
 // create a WriteableBitmap

 WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(

     (int)this.LayoutRoot.ActualWidth,

     (int)this.LayoutRoot.ActualHeight);



 // render the visual element to the WriteableBitmap

 bitmap.Render(this.LayoutRoot, this.transform);



 // request an redraw of the bitmap

 bitmap.Invalidate();
```

**Save**

```
 private void ThumbnailClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

 {

     // pause the capture timer

     this.timer.Stop();

     try

     {

         // locate the WriteableBitmap source for the clicked image

         WriteableBitmap bitmap = ((Image)sender).Source as WriteableBitmap;

         if (null == bitmap)

         {

             MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save");

             return;

         }



         // prompt for a location to save it

         if (this.dialog.ShowDialog() == true)

         {

             // the "using" block ensures the stream is cleaned up when we are finished

             using (Stream stream = this.dialog.OpenFile())

             {

                 // encode the stream

                 JPGUtil.EncodeJpg(bitmap, stream);

             }

         }

     }

     finally

     {

         // restart the capture timer

         this.timer.Start();

     }

 }
```

Comment: what is this.transform? I don't have it, can I use a Unit transform control? can user download saved image from web?

Comment: I would suggest reading the article and not just the code "You can pass a Transform to the Render method to scale, rotate, skew, and/or translate the element being rendered. "

Comment: Your link goes to a 404.